# Intellij to use Maven output directories

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to migrate from eclipse to Intellij, at the moment I have all the projects properly imported (projects are huge and corelated), and maven builds are sucessfully executing. But intellij shows lot of different compilation problems in java files which are not possible as maven is building.

I dont need to run anything with IntelliJ, I just build maven artifact and deploy it on sandbox deployments and use remote debug to work with project. In short I dont need Intellij to compile java files itself, i need it to use maven output directories with class files and only show compilation issues if maven cant build it...

In eclipse I simply disable automatic project build and just edit my java code and build with maven... I dont know what's the alternative here. Any help?

How can I use maven target directories instead of intellij's out directory?

Answer (score 1):

Hum. I think you only need to import your project as a maven project.

Idea will never produce any classes, as long as you don't use "Compile project_name" or "Make project_name" explicitly (unlike eclipse which always build everything by default).

Answer (score 1):

Import your maven projects as maven modules in IntelliJ : http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_and_importing_Maven_projects

IntelliJ is smart enough to figure out what the source folders and class folders are (even when modified in the pom.xml file)

Comment: Ok let me explain, I've imported projects as maven projects they appear as nested maven modules. When i run maven clean install it does everything as expected (note that test sources are compiled too or I'm wrong?), but in idea i get error messages about not found classes (that are actually maven dependencies) and this is happening in test sources and only in one project out of 100 or so...

Comment: I've just excluded that test sources from the project but lets face it thats not the way to do it. In fact Intellij were compiling sources, when i restart it with cache invalidated it shows no error then after it compiles sources (makes project) it shows those errors...

Comment: IntelliJ normally has no problem putting external jars it needs on the classpath, or detecting that some dependencies should simply be module dependencies. You may need to synchronize. Click the refresh icon in the Maven projects view.

Comment: Intellij is *more* maven compliant than eclipse, and not at all forgiving of errors in the pom. Does your project compile and build with command-line maven (totally outside of eclipse)?

Comment: Yes it is compiling fine with cmd mvn, thats why i'm expecting the IDEA to not show any errors (at least no compilation errors), i can see that in my test sources the problem shown by intellij is caused by some sql jar which is somehow not reached by intellij but reached with maven (and i check local repo and it was located there).

Answer (score 1):

Highlight your project root in the project panel and press <kbd>F4</kbd>. Select `Modules` in the project settings window in the upper left. Select your project's parent folder in the long panel to the right of this. On the right of that, in the Path's tab, you'll find your project's output path. You can edit this to be anything you like.

Because I've imported a maven project, my output path end in target/classes and target/test-classes respectively. I have the option to exclude output paths selected.